# How to cancel FaceBook Login page in Web-View

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am implementing **FaceBook Login** using **Manual Login Flow** (Without any SDK) in a **web-Kit/web-view** by calling facebook api as

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?{appid}/etc/etc.
```

from an HTML Page inside a Web-View.

If the user is not logged-in then it opens a facebook login page in `web-view`.
It is shown in the image below.

[image: Facebook Login Page Inside WEB-View]

at this point there is no way to cancel the login and come back to my application from in iPhone. If the user want to cancel the login he must close the application and restart again. which is a painful process.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why don't you use Facebook SDK ?

Comment: I have some limitation and need to go without SDK

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Add a webview and a button(close) to the viewcontroller(it's the viewcontroller where you wish to load the facebook page.
2. You can present this viewcontroller using presentModalViewController (or anything like that).
   eg:

   ```
   _webViewController=[[WebViewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebViewViewController"  bundle:nil];
   [self presentModalViewController:_webViewController animated:YES];
   ```
3. When you're finished done with the facebook or you're in the middle of anything , you can simply press the close button.
   Here you put the following code for the close button action as:

   ```
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   ```

This way you can come back to your application without closing your application. Hope it helps. I've implemented this, feel free to comment in case of any confusion.